# Why are characters in Star Trek so specific when speaking?

Tags: star-trek

Is there an in-universe explanation as to why characters in Star Trek are often excessively specific when speaking?

For example, why refer to a "sonic shower", when they are the standard type of shower on board Voyager and normally such unnecessary detail would be quickly dropped. In real life we rarely refer to our "electric power shower".

Turbolifts, isolinear chips, hyper spanners...

The most famous example is probably Picard's "tea, Earl Grey, hot", which makes you wonder why he doesn't just make that the default option when he asks for "tea", but there are many others.

Out of universe the explanation is probably that it adds some technobable texture to the dialogue and reminds the viewer that it's the future, but is there an in-universe explanation?

Comment: _"tea, Earl Grey, hot"_ - Earl Grey isn't the standard tea bag and whilst tea is generally hot some people would like it warm or even cold. Not everyone knows everyone's drink order. I personally have my preferences engraved on my mug to make it a bit easier.

Comment: I always just assumed that regular (as we would see them) elevators, water showers, spanners etc. are still in use somewhere in the Federation, so they still have to distinguish them.

Comment: This seems excessively broad. People use specific words for specific reasons, for example because some quarters contain real (water) showers, making the distinction relevant. Picard presumably refers to his drink order in specific terms because he's spent most of his life without his own personal replicator, etc

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot on phones and computers you can set up defaults, like when you click on an email address it opens your preferred email app, creates a new email and adds your standard signature at the bottom. Yet Picard apparently can't program his VCR^H^H^H replicator to just give him hot Earl Grey by default. Not even a shortcut button on the control panel for favourite items.

Comment: You... shower in electricity?

Comment: Interesring insight into the in-universe culture. If anything, language today *lags* tech innovations - computers still dump "core", we "dial" and "hang up" phones, and we save data on Solid State "Disks".

Comment: I consider many Star Trek characters to be annoyingly vague, imprecise, and NON specific when speaking.

Comment: If anything, a more "realistic" Star Trek would have characters talking about carrying "pistols" on missions (even though they were actually "phaser pistols", not the chemical projectile kind), plugging in their isolinear "disks", and playing "video games" in "virtual reality" (not "going onto the holodeck"). As mentioned, the problem is that those things don't sound "futuristic" enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Tea, Ceylon-Assam, one lump of sugar and plenty of milk."

Within the universe, adherence to correct technical language is something that sets *professionals* apart from *amateurs*. "This is my rifle and this is my gun" and all that.

Comment: I was wondering about that, but I don't know if there are examples of civilians using similarly explicit language.

Comment: @user, what kind of civilians? Spacers? Scientists?

Comment: Your answer reminds me of the scene where Tom Paris struggles with the replicator and its many soup options. None of the current Starfleet members struggled with the replicator, but the way he gets angry with it makes him look less professional.

Comment: There's also some scenes when asking the computer/replicator systems for something where the system keeps coming back asking for clarifications... it's possible when you know the system's going to do that - you pre-empt it and just give it all the info. in a single sentence instead of the entailing back'n'forth.

Comment: @JonClements if you want to convert that to an answer it will get my up-vote.

Comment: @user 1) it's only covers one part of your question, 2) it's mostly the same as this answer - just pointing out another rationale for why it might occur and 3) your question's currently on hold as too broad...

Comment: While this answer does address a possibly valid issue, it does not answer the basic premise: excess specificity. Even scientists will not add unneeded verbiage. He will go to the diner and ask for "decaf", instead of asking for it by full name and brand, possibly adding, "you know, the only kind of decaffeinated coffee you sell to everyone, all day, every day." _Everyone_ on board has a sonic shower. I'm not sure there can be an in-universe explanation for this; it only serves to tell the story, to narrate their future world against ours.

Comment: ...Additionally, the OP did note to us something computers do for us now: remember preferences. There's really no reason Picard's replicator shouldn't remember his favorite tea. (Unless he gets enough of it from more public replicators, AND those replicators aren't sufficiently tied into the ship's systems enough to know who is asking.)

Comment: To expand on Jon Clement's earlier comment, take for example Google Home. Even though it understands natural speak commands quite well, certain commands do have a syntax to them to make it easier for parsing ("OK Google, <do action> <on/from service> <on/to device>"). You can provide all of the info up front, or you can let Google ask for clarification (ie, which device, if multiple are present and there is no default, or multiple can service the command - like playing music on a speaker or the TV). So who is to say computers in the future can't be the same way to make the  programming easier?

Comment: @Duthomhas - My thinking on this is that with stored preferences... come privacy concerns... the less it sorted about a persons preferences, the less this an issue, so maybe in a communial society such as this, it's designed out to prevent privacy becoming an issue...